# To show that $n!f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: polynomials

If $f(x)$ is a polynomial such that if $y \in\mathbb{Z}$, then $f(y)\in\mathbb{Z}$, show that there exist $n$ such that $n!f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!!To get better answers to your questions you must try to give some information regarding your background knowledge on the subject,your attempt to solve it and detail your question as much as possible.If you do these,you will get better answers and have a nice time in our site.Thanks!!(From a Review)...

Comment: What's $n$?  Obviously if you choose $n$ large enough you can clear all coefficients' denominators.  Is perhaps $n$ the degree of your polynomial?

Comment: And where if $f$ taken from? $\Bbb Q [x]$, $\Bbb R[x]$, $\Bbb C[x]$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A well known result
is that any integer-valued polynomial
is the sum of
integer multiples of
$\binom{x}{k}
=\dfrac{x(x-1)...(x-k+1)}{k!}
$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer-valued_polynomial

By multiplying by
the largest
$k!$,
we get your statement.

Answer (score 2):

[Newton's interpolation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_series#Newton.27s_series) is
$$
f(n) = d_0 \binom{n}{0} + d_1 \binom{n}{1} + d_2 \binom{n}{2} +  d_3 \binom{n}{3} +\cdots
$$
where $d_i$ are the numbers in the first column of the repeated differences array.

This proves that a polynomial takes integral values at integers iff it is an integer linear combination of the binomial polynomials. See [Integer-valued polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer-valued_polynomial).